"TypeError: string argument without an encoding" when retrieving an ORM object
I'm trying to set up an SFTP server in python, using paramiko library.
I'm using a PostgreSQL to store users credentials, by SQLAlchemy library.
When I try to login using FileZilla or WinSCP to the server, it gives me an error in this function:
def authenticate_user(username: str, password:str = None, public_key:str = None) -> bool:
engine = provide_engine()
if not engine:
    return False

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

try:
    stmt = select(User).where(User.username == username)
    user = session.execute(stmt).scalars().first()

    if not user:
        return False

    if password:
        print("Before checking.")
        if user.check_password(password):
            print("After checking.")
            return True
    elif public_key and user.ssh_keys and len(user.ssh_keys) > 0:
        for key in user.ssh_keys:
            if key.public_key == public_key:
                return True
            
    return False
finally:
    session.close()

The error is:
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Unknown exception: string argument without an encoding
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2262, in run
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    handler(m)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 609, in _parse_userauth_request
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    result = self.transport.server_object.check_auth_password(
ERROR:paramiko.transport:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "d:\Files\*******\Python\cr-beta\database_sftp\SFTPServer.py", line 20, in check_auth_password
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    if authenticate_user(username, password=password):
ERROR:paramiko.transport:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "d:\Files\*******\Python\cr-beta\database_sftp\SFTPServer.py", line 98, in authenticate_user
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    user = session.execute(stmt).scalars().first()
ERROR:paramiko.transport:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1786, in first  
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return self._only_one_row(
ERROR:paramiko.transport:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 749, in _only_one_row
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    row: Optional[_InterimRowType[Any]] = onerow(hard_close=True)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1673, in _fetchone_impl
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return self._real_result._fetchone_impl(hard_close=hard_close)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 2259, in _fetchone_impl
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    row = next(self.iterator, _NO_ROW)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 219, in chunks    
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    fetch = cursor._raw_all_rows()
ERROR:paramiko.transport:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 541, in _raw_all_rows
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return [make_row(row) for row in rows]
ERROR:paramiko.transport:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\resultproxy.pyx", line 22, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy.BaseRow.__init__
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\resultproxy.pyx", line 79, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.resultproxy._apply_processors
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 913, in process  
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    value = bytes(value)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR:paramiko.transport:TypeError: string argument without an encoding

I don't understand wher is the problem, also because, the username is stored as string in the Database, and the password i think that is handled well.
Under the declaraton of the User table:
class User(Base):
__tablename__ = USERS_TABLE
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
password_hash = Column(LargeBinary, nullable=False)
created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))

ssh_keys = relationship("SSHKey", back_populates="user")

def set_hashed_password(self, hashed_password: bytes):
    self.password_hash = hashed_password

def set_password(self, password: str):
    self.password_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())

def check_password(self, password: str) -> bool:
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode(), self.password_hash)

I want to specify that i'm trying to login with a username and a password, and not with a ssh key.
UPDATE:
I tried to check the real column type using:
from sqlalchemy import inspect
insp = inspect(engine)
print(list(x["type"] for x in insp.get_columns(USERS_TABLE) if x["name"] == "password_hash"))

and it print [VARCHAR()] in console.
I also check in pgAdmin4 and the type of the column is character varying.

Why if in User class I set column as LargeBinary it is a variable character? Is this the problem?

Looks like paramiko is looking for the passed in string to have encoding information and since it does not failing with  string argument without an encoding.  I'm guessing this may have to do with how FileZilla and WinSCP are formatting the login credentials.

Verify the column type in the actual table. Use from sqlalchemy import inspect and insp = inspect(engine), then print(list(x["type"] for x in insp.get_columns(USERS_TABLE) if x["name"] == "password_hash")). What does it show?

@GordThompson it returns me [VARCHAR()]. I also check in pgAdmin4 and it tells me that is a character varying.

Have you tried removing either SSH/Paramiko or PostgreSQL/SQLAlchemy from the picture? BTW, your formatting is off, please fix that so that it includes a [mcve].

PostgreSQL tables has been created with a wrong type. The password_hashed column type was character varying, becouse the type was changed later.
